# validation error in archiving the app using Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, xcode-6.2

I have met this problem when archiving my app using Xcode 6.2 which I tried to solve for several days.. I can success in running it on my phone or the simulator. And I also created provisioning file for it.

Is there anything more I should fix to avoid it?

> Validate
>   /Users/-/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Inclinometer-cndcxrakllqvfibksraeytztomxi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Inclinometer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Inclinometer.app
>   cd /Users/-/Desktop/apps/Inclinometer export
>   PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   export PRODUCT_TYPE=com.apple.product-type.application
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
>   /Users/-/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Inclinometer-cndcxrakllqvfibksraeytztomxi/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Inclinometer/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/Inclinometer.app
>
> dyld: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_DVTITunesConnectProxy
>   Referenced from:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/../../../../../../SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/DVTFoundation
>   in
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
>   Command
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
>   failed with exit code 5

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved the problem by a walk-around method. I have no idea what was wrong with my app or settings. When I tested with a brand new app, the archive would show the same error message. So I guess something in Xcode was wrong. I searched to the file Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
and changed it with another one. Then there is no error message when archiving my app.